# Is it possible to validate an enumerable model using FluentValidation without enabling implicit validation of child properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, fluentvalidation

Given the following model, validator and controller (in ASP.NET Core 3.1):

```cs
public sealed class Model
{
    public string Property { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
{
    public ModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.Property).NotEmpty();
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public sealed class TheController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult PostSomething(IEnumerable<Model> model)
    {
        // Do something
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Is there a way of validating the `IEnumerable<Model>` model of `TheController.PostSomething` without enabling `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` in my startup class like below?

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    .AddFluentValidation(c => c.ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true);
```

I have, so far, been unable to find a way of successfully validating the enumerable model without setting `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties = true`.

**Update**: when changing the signature of `PostSomething`, and adding and registering an additional validator (as below) validation does occur.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostSomething(List<Model> model)
{
    // Do something
    return Ok();
}

public sealed class ListOfModelValidator : AbstractValidator<List<Model>>
{
    public ListOfModelValidator()
    {
        RuleForEach(m => m).SetValidator(new ModelValidator());
    }
}
```

However, this feels wrong. It also causes a problem with the `ValidationProblemDetails` response that is returned. The index of the element with the validation error will have the name of the lambda parameter prefixed, so instead of `[0].Property` it will be `m[0].Property`. I have been unable to to find a way of removing the name of the lambda parameter, either using `WithName` or a custom `DisplayNameResolver`.

However, this approach feels wrong. I'd rather not have to change the signature of `PostSomething` or add something that feels like a kludge to remove the lambda parameter name.

While I could just enable `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` it has the potential to cause problems with some changes that I need to make so I would prefer to avoid it if possible.

Comment: similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288548/how-to-validate-directly-against-a-listt/45615136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

As of version 9.4.0 of FluentValidation, the [`ImplicitlyValidateRootCollectionElements`](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#implicit-validation-of-collection-type-models) option is available, which will enable validation of collection-type models without also enabling implicit validation of child properties. It can be enabled the same way as implicit child model validation, for example:

```cs
services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => {
   fv.ImplicitlyValidateRootCollectionElements = true;
});
```

### Model binding and implicit child property validation

Model binding deserializes `ICollection<TElement>`, `IEnumerable<TElement>` and `IList<TElement>` as `List<TElement>` (see [`CollectionModelBinder.CreateEmptyCollection`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/634b50eeee1311382aee774ff32f0b54fdbb7c0f/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/CollectionModelBinder.cs#L239)).

When `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` is `false`, FluentValidation will only attempt to find a validator that matches the bound type of the action method parameter, which will be `List<TElement>` or in my example `List<Model>`. Therefore, there is no need to change the signature of `TheController.PostSomething` but the validator must derive from `AbstractValidator<List<TElement>>`.

When `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` is `true`, FluentValidation will attempt to find a validator for type `TElement`, so validation of the elements of a root collection model will occur. However, FluentValidation will also validate child properties of `TElement` where a matching validator is registered and `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` is `true`. In my case I would like validation of collection elements to occur but I do not want automatic validation of the child properties of each element to occur so enabling implicit validation of child properties is not suitable.

### Overriding the `RuleForEach` property name

Unfortunately, trying to remove the lambda parameter name by using `WithName` or `OverridePropertyName` and passing `string.Empty` fails because a null or empty property name is always overwritten (in v9.3.0, see [`CollectionPropertyRule.InvokePropertyValidator`](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/blob/6f524bb70ef61c032f2c3e87a1787c6a979970ec/src/FluentValidation/Internal/CollectionPropertyRule.cs#L166)). This makes sense for collection properties, for which `RuleForEach` appears to be primarily designed, but not for root collections.

With explicit validation, there appears to be two ways to remove the lambda parameter name from the validation error, both of which are a bit of a kludge.

1. Override `Validate` and rewrite the property name.
2. Implement [`IValidatorInterceptor`](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#validator-interceptors) and rewrite the property name in `AfterMvcValidation`.

### Summary

The available options are:

1. Set `ImplicitlyValidateChildProperties` to `true` and make sure the design works with automatic validation of child properties.
2. Use explicit validation and override `Validate` or use a validator interceptor to rewrite the property name after validation.
3. Redesign the model (although whether this is a feasible option obviously depends on various other factors).